# html figure-tag size doesn't adjust to the image size, can't find why

Tags: html, size, figure

Please check out this url (with your debugger of choice) and the pictures in it, it's for a class I'm taking atm and I can't figure out why the figure-tags are using the full available width instead of just inheriting height and width from their respective images? :P

http://www.student.bth.se/~kaoa13/htmlphp/bmo/artiklar.php

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance does not work the way your question implies it does.  Since the `<img>` tags are inside the `<figure>` tag, the `<img>` tags are the children of the `<figure>` tag.  This means that the `<img>` tags will inherit the width of the `<figure>` tag, not the other way around.  If you want to override this inheritance you must set width values in the CSS.  You will have to set the `<figure>` width if you do not want them to use the full width.

Comment: But doesn't every tag "try" to be as small as possible? Why would figure have a default full-screen size which is what seems to be going on on my site? :P
Thanks a lot for the quick answer btw! :)

Comment: No.  Tags actually default to the width of their parent element minus border and padding.  If you inspect your page, you only set the width for the `<body>` tag.  It is set to 934px.  Everything else (`<article>`, `<p>`, `<div>`, `<figure>`, etc.) inherits that size.  The reason the images are smaller than the `<figure>` is because they have a definite size that the browser will display them at.  So, in effect, everything tries to be as big as possible due to the nature of inheritance in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question. Might be someone will help the answer.

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    object-fit: contain;
}

figure {
    overflow: hidden,
    backgroundSize : contain,
}
```